# How to handle date and time in application when it is used from different geographical locations?

Tags: date, time

Lets suppose, if a user from India enters some data into the database with its own local timestamp at 5:30  a.m and at the same time a user from U.S.A want to see the data, at that time he will feel very weird because that time which is entered in the database has not arrived yet. How to handle this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

Store all dates and times as UTC date and time values and convert them to the local date and time whenever they are displayed.